# iOS override a Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

I have a tableview controller and I would like to override the segue for the final row. Instead of going to the standard destination view controller I want to send it to another controller. How do I do this?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                            indexPathForSelectedRow];
    long row = [myIndexPath row];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowLocationsTableView"])
    {
        LocationsTableViewController *ViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        ViewController.categoryDetailModel = @[_categoryTitle[row],
                                            _categoryImages[row]];
    }
}
```

This is the current prepareForSegue and I would like to change it. I would like to send it to another view controller using a segue "aboutCat". How do I do this?

I don't understand what happens between prepareForSegue [current] and viewDidLoad [destination]. Thanks

**Sideeffects**

Initial problem was solved by 'Nikita Took' yet there are some side effects

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    long row = [myIndexPath row];
    if ([_categoryTitle[row] isEqualToString:@"About"])
    {
        NSLog(@"SKIPPING PREPARE");
    } 
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowLocationsTableView"])
    {
        LocationsTableViewController *ViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        ViewController.categoryDetailModel = @[_categoryTitle[row],
                                            _categoryImages[row]];
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) 
    {
        // I assume you have 1 section
        NSLog(@"DIDSELECTROW");
        NSLog(@"INDEX PATH %i", indexPath.row + 1);
        NSLog(@"%i", [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]);
        if (indexPath.row + 1 == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"ABOUT");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aboutCat" sender:self];
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"ELSE");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLocationsTableView" sender:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Now the about works!!! But if I click on another row which is one of the mainSegue. It will call the subview controller 2x. I can verify this with NSLOG statements in the detailview viewdidload. The issue is that now the navigation controller takes two steps to return home.

[home] -> [detail view] -> [same detail view]

I can verify that the didselectrowatindexpath happens before the prepareforsegue

Any ideas why two segues are preformed?

Comment: then add the another one segue in didselctrowatIndexpath

Comment: Can I just add that method? Any other actions needed?

Comment: u need some different methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have two segues: `MainSegue` (for all rows except the last one) and `LastRowSegue` (for the last row) you can do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        // I assume you have 1 section
        if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LastRowSegue" sender:self];
        } else {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainSegue" sender:indexPath];
        }
    }
}
```

Try this for `prepareForSegue`. If it's not what you need, please explain what do you mean

> It works but I'm getting double layered table views

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MainSegue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = sender;
        LocationsTableViewController *locationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        locationController..=categoryDetailModel = @[_categoryTitle[selectedIndexPath.row], _categoryImages[selectedIndexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but I'm getting double layered table views. Should I remove the prepareforsegue method?

Comment: yes, you shouldn't change segue identifier or segue destination in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Where would I place this code (From prepareforsegue)?: This is for the MainSegue, but how do I pass these values -> '        LocationsTableViewController *ViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];
        
        ViewController.categoryDetailModel = @[_categoryTitle[row],
                                                _categoryImages[row]];'

Comment: Updated question with sideeffects. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in prepareForSegue -- the source and destination view controllers are already defined by the time prepareForSegue is called. You need to make two segues from your controller (not the cell) and call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender" in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Choose which segue to perform based on the indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

int lastIndex=[tableArray count]-1;
        if (indexPath.row == lastIndex) {

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                                NSString* viewType = @"MenuVC";//u can have the identifier of the LocationViewCOntroller or where ever you wanna go from here
                                UIViewController* viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewType];
                                self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, nil];
        } else {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"usualSegue" sender:self];

        }
}
```